# Counting records of a table with multiple foreign keys (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with various tables whose records can be tagged, so I have a `tags` table, and a `tag_associations` table that relates tags to other "taggable" tables via multiple foreign keys, and also to an "owning" user -- my fields are something like the following:

- tag_association_id (primary key)
- user_id (tag association creator)
- tag_id (related tag)
- artist_id (tagged artist, can be null)
- album_id (tagged album, can be null)
- track_id (tagged track, can be null)

I basically want to count all items that have been tagged a particular tag -- so something along the results of this query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(ta.tag_association_id) AS how_many
FROM
    tag_associations AS ta
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON ta.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE
    ta.tag_id = '480'
    AND u.user_status = 'active'
```

But the problem with this query lies in cases where the same tag has been applied to the same item by multiple users, so if 2 different users tag the artist 'Bobby Jones Band' as 'rad', it counts both of the tag associations where I just want to count it once. I tried adding this to the above:

```
GROUP BY ta.artist_id, ta.album_id, ta.track_id
```

...which got me close, but didn't yield the exact results I needed -- it gave me multiple row results of different counts. Is there any magic I can use in a case like this and keep it in a single query? While remaining as efficient as possible, of course :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, then your `GROUP BY` should almost do the job.

This solution should get the unique rows from `tag_associations` and count them.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tag_associations AS ta 
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON ta.user_id = u.user_id
    WHERE ta.tag_id = '480' 
    AND u.user_status = 'active' 
    GROUP BY ta.artist_id, ta.album_id, ta.track_id
) x
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter! When I run this I get an error: "Every derived table must have its own alias". It appears to me that the results of the subquery are being used in the FROM, and therefore as the table being queried against in the outer query -- is that right? In which case it makes sense that the results wouldn't come though...

Comment: Sorry. I added the alias (`x`), please try again.